# gulp-jade: как не компилировать по отдельности выбранные файлы

Tags: gulp, jade, pug

Если в `sass` для того, чтобы файл не компилировался по отдельности, достаточно поставить нижнее подчёркивание первым символом имени файла, то можно ли сделать нечто подобное с gulp-jade?

В качестве примера, зачем это нужно: у нас есть базовый шаблон `base.jade`, включающий основу макета, а всё, что между тэгами `body`, мы прописываем в дочерних макетах (получать родительских макет будем через 'extends'). Понятно, что нам не нужен выходной 'base.html', потому что он не содержит никакого вывода в браузер, но давайте предположим, что таких `base.html` несколько (`base1.html`, `base2.html`, ... , 'baseN.html'). Как проще всего исключить все эти файлы из компиляции по отдельности? Будет ли достаточно шаблона выборки `glob` или имеет смысл задействовать дополнительные средства?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал вот так.
Для компилирования в gulp указал бы `src` - `templates/*.pug`
А некомпилируемые шаблоны держал бы в `templates/layouts/`, например.

Answer (score 0):

Gulp можно попросить не компилировать конкретные файлы, поставив знак восклицаеия в начале их пути

```js
return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.jade', '!./src/blocks/**/*.jade', '!./src/include.jade'])
```